# Filter DataGridView by boolean

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, dataview, rowfilter

I'm trying to filter a DataGridView by bool values (column containing Checkboxes).

I looked up several solutions and none worked for me.

This one looks plain simple and logic, but it just erases all the entries.

```
            DataView dv = new DataView();
            dv.RowFilter = "Finished = 0";
            dgvMain.DataSource = dv;
```

The Column's header text is "Finished" as well as the name is "Finished".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you already tried to set the DataSource before you are going to filter?

Comment: I'm not certain what you actually mean.

Comment: Try to swap line 2 and 3 of your code.

Comment: That does not work unfortunately

Comment: `"Finished = false"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a DataTable for you DataSource (your comment says List) then I'd recommend you switch to it so that the checkboxes are more closely associated with each object in your DataGridView. You can then filter the DataTable by putting it into a BindingSource (which has a Filter property) and then using that binding as the DataGridView's DataSource.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form {

    public MainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // change string to whatever your object type is
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("object column", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CheckBoxColumn", typeof(bool)));

        dt.Rows.Add("row1", 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("row2", 0);
        dt.Rows.Add("row3", 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("row4", 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("row5", 0);

        BindingSource binding = new BindingSource();
        binding.DataSource = dt;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = binding;
    }

    private void filterDGV(string rowFilter)
    {
        BindingSource source = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        source.Filter = rowFilter;
    }

    private void FilterToCheckedRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filterDGV("CheckBoxColumn = 1");
    }

    private void FilterToUncheckedRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filterDGV("CheckBoxColumn = 0");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Engine.Book]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'." since the DataGridView is bound to a List actually.

Comment: @Smarc was my answer able to help you?